# How do I set JSHint options using Chirpy?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, plugins, chirpy, jshint

I am using Chirpy (http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) inside Visual Studio 2010 and I've got JSHint running.  The problem is, I don't know how to set the options for JSHint, or even to see what options are on by default.

I tried the inline syntax (see below) but Chirpy seems to ignore that.  Does anyone know how to set the options?

```
/*jshint evil: true, boss: true */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am slightly embarrassed but also pleased to say that the inline syntax does work.  However because of the default options it is hard to tell.

I read through most of the Chirpy code base as well as the code base for UglifyJS to figure out that Chirpy just sets all the values for the options to ***false***.  This means it doesn't require much of your JavaScript code.

To turn on the strictest JSHint options, using this at the top of your JS file:

```
/*jshint bitwise: true, curly: true, eqeqeq: true, immed: true, newcap: true, 
noarg: true, noempty: true, nonew: true, nomen: true, onevar: true, 
plusplus: true, regexp: true, undef: true, strict: true, white: true */
```

Note, you cannot put a space between **/*** and **jshint**.  Chirpy will ignore it if you do.